# ADT bundle doesnt recognise my path on ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, path, bundle

ı m tryıng to ınstall ADT bundle  ( android development kit) to my ubuntu 13.04ı download my bundle and ı wanted to add some PACKAGES  from android SDK manager then ıt gave me an error that

***Stopping ADB server failed (code -1).
Unable to run 'adb': Cannot run program "/home/mehmet/Android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platform-tools/adb": error=2, No such file or directory.
Starting ADB server failed (code -1).***
but ı checked that  my  directory is correct

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the folder and file exist?  Open a terminal and paste the following:  `cd /home/mehmet/Android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platform-tools/` then press enter.  If that works without error, type `ls` and enter and see if adb is listed

Comment: ıt gave me something like this

Comment: ls
adb  api  fastboot  NOTICE.txt  source.properties  systrace
mehmet@Hiko-comp:~/Android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platform-tools$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it to your path and set permission to the adb file.